# Velux blackout blind does not 'click' onto new securing brackets

Tags: windows

I replaced a blackout blind on my Velux window, but the grey plastic securing brackets had also to be replaced.  The new ones came with the new blind.  I cannot get the blackout blind cartridge to click into position.  It just drops back out.  As far as I can see, there is only one approach when bringing the blind cartridge towards the brackets, straight up towards the Velux window, so that the blind's black side fittings slide over the grey brackets - but no click!

Comment: If you would [edit] your post to include a picture of the blinds & brackets, that would help a lot. Also, a picture/scan of the instruction sheet where it explains how they mount, or at a minimum, the name/model number of your particular blinds so someone could search out the instructions for themselves.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted Velux? You may need to ask if sizing of blind has been altered since the time yours was originally purchased, or if installation method has changed.